# Do function arguments violate encapsulation?

Tags: function, parameters, arguments, encapsulation, getter-setter

This question is related to OOP practice in general.
Say we have a class with a public function accepting passed in arguments from outside of the object. Is that not a violation of encapsulation in itself? On the other hand why is this practice used so widely? After all the constructor of the class and member variables are kind of "by-passed" when calling the function. As an relatively new programmer to OOP and my understanding of encapsulation my function parameters are passed into the object through setters, so that I keep all of my functions without any arguments using the passed in member variables only. 
I know that certain arguments can be passed in through the constructor (BTW, I use dependency injection), but what if those parameters change after the object is being instantiated? There must be a way to change those values after the object is created. So far I found no other option than using setters to accomplish this task, but there is a long lasting discussion among programmers about getters and setters to be "evil" or at least considered no good programming practice. 
Can anyone tell my where I missed the point and how to solve this dilemma in a clean way?
Many thanks in advance for any support.

Here is a concrete very simple example using C#:

we have a form in a windows form project holding 3 textboxes ,named textBox1 and textBox2 and textBox3.

The task is to add values of textBox1 and textBox2 and returning the result to textBox3 using class AddTextboxValues instantiated by event handler any time the value of textBox1 or textBox2 changes:

The way I see it often and ask if is violation of encapsulation:

```
public class AddTextBoxValues
{
    public double TextBoxValueSum(double textBox1value, double textBox2Value)
    {
       return textBox1value + textBox2Value;
    }
}
```

This is the way I use at the moment as per my understanding of encapsulation:

```
public class AddTextBoxValues
{
    private double textBox1Value;
    private double textBoxValue2;
    private double textBoxValue3;

    public double TextBox1Value
    {
        set { textBox1Value = value; }
    }

    public double TextBoxValue2
    {
        set { textBoxValue2 = value; }
    }

    public double TextBoxValue3
    {
        get { return textBoxValue3; }
    }


    public void TextBoxValueSum()
    {
        textBoxValue3= textBox1Value + textBoxValue2;
    }

}
```

This has also the advantage that it can be injected into the form constructor.

Any comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd give a concrete example - it sounds like you're confusing the state of the object with other state it needs to *handle*. (For example, a date formatter would need to know the format it's meant to use, but it's then passed "the date to format" and that's never part of the state of the object itself.)

Comment: Well, those are two different ways of achieving the same result - but do you really *want* the textbox values to be part of the state of the class? Do you think that in *all* cases they should be?

Comment: And what definition of "encapsulation" are you using that would suggest it's "bypassed" by using method parameters?

Comment: the result is the same, but which one is the more elegant/correct way? Remember my question was targeted to violence of encapsulation(is it violence in the first place or not?). Could you please specify what you mean by "state of the class" and "all cases" for my particular example?

Comment: I meant the state of the *object*, really. Why do you believe an object should have to change its state (i.e. the value of its fields) just to work on data? The "all cases" part was really "do you think this is universally applicable"? Fundamentally the idea that parameters should never be used sounds like a very, very bad idea to me, which would make coding much more painful. Yes, if you had an `Adder` class you *could* create a new object every time you wanted it to add two numbers, but why would you want to? But it's hard to write a specific answer without knowing the background.

Comment: Maybe "object state" is my missing piece of mosaic. Regarding definition of encapsulation, I always think of the objects as "baloons" having only one open end to enter and exit data (referring to controlled member variables by setters) but to forbid to "sting" it with a needle(ref. to argumented functions), which might be a totally wrong approach.Regarding your idea about the Adder class what if it is injected into the constructor of the form, in that case the object is created only one time and you can just update the variables any time the textboxes change and read out the textBox3 variable.

Comment: But you shouldn't *need* to change the state of the Adder object in order to get it to do its job. I think you basically need to read up a bit more on what encapsulation is really about, and possibly just do some more coding... the idea of banning parameterized methods would be really horrible IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much Jon Skeet, you are a real professional.
You diagnosed my problem exactly and opened my eyes for the lack of knowledge to understand and find a solution to my own question. It was indeed a deeper understanding of encapsulation and "object state" which built the missing piece of my puzzle.
Everything seems logic and clear now for me and I hope it will help others in the future,too.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples are not object oriented programming. They are examples of procedural programming.

First "class" is, in fact, just a **namespace** wrapping `TextBoxValueSum` function.
Second "class" is just a **structure** with public fields (there is no difference between getters-setters and public fields).

If you want to use real object oriented programming, you should think of objects, that they are representation of *things*.
In your case, I'd write class `Sum` which is a real thing that represent **one, specific sum**:

```
class Sum {
  private double a, b;
  public Sum (double a, double b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
  public double value() { return this.a + this.b; }
}
```

Comment: do I have to create and dispose the object of the sum class for each and every sum operation? Then how would an OOP handle dependency injection ?, if DI is important in OOP the next question comes up: The problem would be that the object is injected into the form without knowing the operands at initialization, it would be created just once when the form gets created and needs to change input values throughout it's lifetime(which is equivalent to the form's lifetime) to build new sums whenever textbox values change. So how can we change values after the object is being created?

Comment: You can use factory (it can create not only `Sum` object, but also some different objects such as `Difference` and so on) and inject it.
`void clientFunction(NumberFactory numFactory) {
double sum = numFactory.sum(textBox1.value, textBox2.value).value();
}`